# How to add a comment in a spreadsheet on a tab with a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

I have an accounting spreadsheet for each month of the year consists of 31 tabs appointed to the date
Ex Format '15 -03-2015 'for the month of March

I am looking for a script that can put a comment on the tab of the current date and possibly displayed the tab of the date this at the opening of the document with a trigger of course.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a spreadsheet file named 'March' and there are 31 tabs, '1' to '31'. You can add the following code and set the trigger to let it run every time the spreadsheet is opened.

```
function goToTodaysTab(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() , "d");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);

  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  cell.setNote("This comment is written on today's A1 cell.");
}
```

Let me know if it helped or not. :)

Comment: Yes GAS work correctly .function goToTodaysTab(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() , "d"+"-0"+"M"+"-"+"y");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);

  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

  var cell = sheet.getRange("A40");
  cell.setNote("Aujourd'hui est un nouveau jour !");
}

Answer (score 2):

There's doesn't seem to be a way to add comments since they were [changed](http://googleforwork.blogspot.com/2012/09/google-spreadsheets-now-with-discussions.html) to be more discussion oriented. However, what you *can* do is add a note with [setNote()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNote(String)).

```
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

   var cell = ss.getRange("<Range>");
   cell.setNote("<Note>");
```

As far as choosing the correct sheet, you can do so with [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)). Create a `new Date()`, which should get you the current Date and Time. Parse out the time and then pass that into `getSheetByName()` as a string.

For setting which sheet is displayed at the beginning, use [setActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setActiveSheet(Sheet)), within the trigger [onOpen()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function goToTodaysTab(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() , "d"+"-0"+"M"+"-"+"y");
```

//i must put zero to have the same format but don'twork with october november december :i resolve this later

```
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(date);

  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);

  var cell = sheet.getRange("A40");
  cell.setNote("Aujourd'hui est un nouveau jour !");
```

//with a comment that would be more fun and visible !!!
    }

Comment: You just need to use "MM" instead of "M" to get rid of "0".